# Ansible - How to check for specific substring when using loop 'until'?

Tags: automation, ansible, switching

I have a task to Check if my switch has rebooted and I want to run the task until it returns a successful ping. Switch I have is Aruba 2530 and when I ping manually on it, I get a following string in return:

> 192.168.12.200 is alive, time = 2 ms

My idea is to check for the word "alive" from the return string to see the ping has been successful. Is this even an ideal way to go with? Oh and I am using modules from https://github.com/aruba/aruba-switch-ansible

The task I have looks like this:

```
  arubaos_switch_ssh_cli:
    ip: "{{ ansible_host }}"
    user: "{{ ansible_user }}"
    password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
    show_command: "ping 192.168.12.200"
  register: ping_result
  retries: 12
  delay: 5
  until: ???"
```

I've tried to Google the answer and tried several different syntaxes. Most of the stuff I've found are considering condition 'when' so I am not sure how 'when' and 'until' compare to each other when looking at their syntaxes.

I've tried following:

```
"'alive' in ping_result.cli_output"

"ping_result.cli_output | search('alive')

"{{ 'alive' in ping_result.cli_output }}"
```

and several others that haven't been working...

Thanks to everyone in advance!

Comment: Print *ping_result* ``-debug: var=ping_result`` and see the details.

Answer (score 0):

A little hard to be sure without a sample of your registered var, but I think this is what you are looking for:

```
until: ping_result.cli_output is search('alive')
```

Worth to note:

- The task parameter `until` (as [`when`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement), `failed_when`...) is directly interpreted as a jinja2 template string. So you should never put double curly braces around your expressions there.
- Ansible [tests](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html) are not filters and should not be used as such (i.e. with the pipe (`|`) sign).